# Discrepancy between user counts on Leagues versus Users page

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation-leagues, users-page

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/

```
Stack Overflow
Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers
total users: 516,338
```

https://stackoverflow.com/users

```
Num of pages   =   9826
Users per page = x   36
Approx count   =   353k
```

Just wanted to know how each count is derived.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The users page doesn't cover unregistered users.

Comment: This is correct.  stackexchange.com is using the API and includes registered and unregistered users.