# Bug in new user page display?

Tags: bug, status-completed, users, users-page

On [CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), in the old user page rendering, we had 106 pages of users, 35 to a page. In the new user page rendering, we appear to have 58 pages of users, 36 to a page. We appear to have lost nearly half our users!

Comment: Proof required.

Comment: Somewhat related - (User count mismatch) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81260/156011. The page http://stackexchange.com/leagues/44/week/cstheory shows a user count of 3932, closer to your 106 x 35 claim than the current 58 x 36

Comment: I can't give proof because I can't access the old page. but your data seems right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page count should now be stable and complete.

For a day there we were (hackishly) excluding users with 101 rep that were associated, they had done nothing *but* associate (in 99% of cases).  We're still working on `/users`, today we made this much better.  We're not filtering both association bonuses and suspension reputation changes out of the `/users` rep intervals.

Answer (score 1):

The new users page doesn't cover unregistered users anymore.

Comment: Actually, the users page [never reliably covered unregistered users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49764/is-there-a-way-to-sift-through-a-list-of-unregistered-users).

Comment: @Grace: on Stackoverflow, displaying unregistered users was turned off around summer of 2010 and, I thought, with the reason to save paging performance.

Comment: The change predated the launch of Stack Exchange 2.0, so I had always operated under the assumption that they just kept that functionality. Hah, there's no way for me to check anymore, though.